# Can servlet be called without configuration from jsp page?

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

I am having some trouble in context of jsp-servlet.I know that if I use @WebServlet() for servlet-mapping, I have no required to configure web.xml file and vice-versa.

I have a simple **test.jsp** page.It looks like:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> Form test </title>
</head>
<body>

     <form action='HelloWorld' method='doGet' >

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">

     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

My **web.xml** file is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>NewProject</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>test.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And my servlet class which name is **HelloWorld.java** is given below :

```
package FirstPack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


//@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloWorld() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");

        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("Hello World");

        out.println("</body></html>");

    }

}
```

Please note that **@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")** annotation in **HelloWorld.java** class.I have kept this annotation in the comment line.My **web.xml** file is not configured also.But My eclipse IDE does not show any error.It gives correct output.

My question is how to test.jsp file found HelloWorld.java class where there is no existing the path location of HelloWorld.java class.

I am using :

- Java ee 6
- Servlet version is 3.1
- Tomcat server 9.0

Comment: Either the web.xml entry or the annotation will be necessary to allow the HelloWorld class be picked up as a servlet. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: once clear the project and then try.might be it taking old class with @webservlet annotation.

Comment: Just I am checking that if I do not configure web.xml file or do not use @WebServlet() what types of error it will show.But I am surprised that my IDE does not show any error.

Comment: @Sanjay Patel . You are right.It was a simple mistake. Sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the form

```
 <form action='HelloWorld' method='doGet' >
```

This tag where `action = 'HelloWorld'` page which is a servlet and let its access this file  from a jsp file.

Check this tag in the test.jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

Web.xml Entry should be like this:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.packagename.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: As far as I know, Tomcat 9.0 support annotation based configuration.When I used @WebServlet it's all ok. But when I used deployment descriptor for configuration, my server returned a messege like this 'localhost failed to start'.#TIA